# Storing Model in Session VS Recreating It

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there any danger to use one of the 2 following methods? Is there any best practice?

I'm wondering if I will hit a wall when there will be many user online at the same time on the website.

1. Storing Model in Session for later reuse

   ```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       var model = new Model();
       Session["Model"] = model;
       return View(model);
   }

   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Index(FormCollection fc)
   {
       var model = (Model)Session["Model"];
       //Update stuff
       return View(model);
   }
   ```
2. Recreating it on every requests

   ```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       var model = new Model();
       return View(model);
   }

   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Index(FormCollection fc)
   {
       var model = new Model();
       //Update stuff
       return View(model);
   }
   ```

Each model :

- might contain a lot of calls to the database (it can take some time to
  initialize them)
- might contain list of information (a lot of data)

**Edit**

Feels like most avoid trying to answer the question and got stuck on unimportant details to the question.

I accepted the only answer which was able to stay on topic.

Atavari answer is completely off topic and didn't understood the question at all.

Comment: A model should not communicate directly with the database. A model should be a representation of some concept within your domain. You should have some sort of data layer that retrieves your models from the database and provides them to the controllers (and also can save changes back to the DB). Often, this is a Repository class, or `DbContext` if you're using Entity Framework. Retrieving your model might be something like `DbContext context = new DbContext(); ProductModel product = context.Products.Where(p => p.ProductId == Id).Single();`, then you'd pass your product to your view.

Comment: @mason Could you stay on topic please. Whether or not your database call should be in the model or controller is a completely different topic and is irrelevant to this question. No matter where you make the call to the database, the cost will be the same.

Comment: Surely it's not off topic if you are asking for best practice and your way of doing things is fundamentally not best practice.

Comment: @AndyNichols Best practice on the question, not an entirely different one.

Comment: @Gudradain The cost as far as how long it takes it to retrieve the information will be the same. But following a completely flawed architecture will cost you much development time and lead to an application that is untestable and unmaintainable. I realize it's not pleasant to hear that you might need to restructure how you're doing things, but I'm trying to save you many headaches down the road. You may not think it's important, but I'm in the process of refactoring an application that was similar to yours now, and it'd be much easier if it was done right in the beginning.

Comment: As far as me "not staying on topic" imagine this: you walk into the doctor's office because you're worried you may have broken your hand. They do X Rays and tell you that they may have found a tumor, but you tell the doc that he needs to stay on topic, you're there to learn about your hand, not cancer. But the doc knows this cancer is going to be a big deal if you don't address it, a much bigger problem than a broken hand. Stack Overflow is the doc here. Listen to us, we/I am trying to save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: @mason I agree that the cost of a bad architecture is huge. But do you think  I don't have any? I use a 3-layered architecture already, I use EF, I have repository and stubs of those repo and everything is already backed by unit test. Like I said, it's off topic but thank you for the concern.

Comment: You stated in your question that each model communicates to the database. If you are properly following the repository pattern, that *should not happen*. You may have unit tests, but I seriously doubt their ability to isolate the models to test them properly if you're not following proper separation of concerns.

Comment: @mason Clearly, you know my code better than myself. Thank you for showing me the right way and not answering the question...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It depends on how many users you really have. Using session can be comfortable and easy but scalability may become an issue.

If you use it just to improve performance, I would suggest you to use cache instead. Take care that objects in cache can expire so you have always to check whether they are still there. Cache is better than session because it is self optimized. If memory gets low it's automatically cleaned, while session variables are never cleaned (unless of course when session expires).

Comment: This answer is irrelevant. You should never use cache for such purpose.

Comment: Why? you put the object in cache for five minutes, what's the problem with it? You should never use the session for performance reason, and the question was about performance

Comment: The question is about performance, but you don't even need to save your model. You send your Model to the View using Controller, and get it back from View in your Controller's post Action. Why do you even want to save it?

Comment: @ataravati I have been trying to tell you that you completely missed the question. In the question, the only thing I care about is : should I save data coming from the database or should I retrieve it from the database everytime. This answer is on subject, yours is completely off.

Answer (score 3):

Both of those methods are wrong. Your post action should receive the model, not a `FormCollection` object.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Model model)
{
    //Update stuff
    return View(model);
}
```

And, you usually redirect to a different page after the Add/Update is successful, and only return the same View if there's validation error. So, your post action should look more like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Model model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       //Update stuff
       //return to a different page or whatever needs to be done 
       //after a successful update
    } 

    // If model is not valid...
    return View(model);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If there are properties in your model that are not posted to your action (like a `SelectList` for a dropdown), you'll only need them if you want to return the same View (normally when there's validation error). In that case you don't have to recreate your model. You just repopulate those properties.

Let's say your model has a property called Items. This is how your actions should look like:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new Model();
    model.Items = GetItems();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Model model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       //Update stuff
       //return to a different page or whatever needs to be done 
       //after a successful update
    } 

    // If model is not valid...
    model.Items = GetItems();
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Why -1? Can you at least explain?

Comment: -1 Because it doesn't answer the question and it contains "error". Using model binding is indeed a good technique (and I use it) but you cannot put all the information contained in a model in the post method of a webpage. For example, if the model contain a list of objects to display on the page, you will not put every single object in a form to later be able to rebuild it with model binding. It makes no sense.

Comment: Using model binding is not a good technique, it's THE technique. By the way, where's the "error" in the code? Check my updated answer.

Comment: Good answer. Posting the model is standard practice. Only returning the view on error but redirecting on success is also good practice and is known as the post-redirect-get pattern. It helps prevent the issue where refreshing the page after a successful post tries to resend the post data.

Comment: @AndyNichols So, if your view contains a list of 1000 objects that you just want to display on the screen (not edit), you will include these 1000 objects in a form just so that the complete model can be reconstructed?

Comment: I have never had anywhere near 1000 objects on the screen and it suggests a design flaw in the application. If I did then yes, I would hold the object data (no logic) in the model and have it in the form.

Comment: @ataravati So, you suggest recreating it (well the missing part). (-1 removed)

Comment: @Gudradain, no that's not what I'm suggesting. What I'm suggesting is repopulating the properties that need to be repopulated in case you have to return to the same View. These two are completely different things.

Comment: You should not "recreate" your model. The model should be coming through a post from your View.

Comment: @ataravati My "ViewModel" is always coming from a post on my webpage and contain only post data. My "Model" is always constructed by the business logic layer and contain data coming from the database. I should have specified that from the start.

Comment: @Gudradain, you're doing it right, but what I was talking about was the model in the code in your question. That model (ViewModel) should be coming from the View through model binding. You shouldn't be recreating it in an action post. And, the fact that you have chosen the other answer as the correct answer shows that you still don't get it. :D

Comment: @ataravati This model in the question is the "Model" not the "ViewModel"

Comment: @Gudradain, then, it's not recommended to use your model directly. You should create a ViewModel for this purpose. But, anyway, that's a separate issue.

Comment: @ataravati it's a simplified example. Of course I pass a ViewModel to my view, the database data is hold in the model and the ViewModel transform the model data in something the view can understand. But all that is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @Gudradain, again, I don't care how you do it. I'm just talking about this specific question. You are passing a Model to your View through your Controller. Your POST Action should receive the Model as a parameter (ModelBinding). So, you'll never recreate your Model in your post action, neither you save it in the session or cache. Period. That doesn't make any sense if you are familiar with the MVC concept.